# How can I create Google Alert in php

Tags: php, rss, alert, google-alerts

I have spend much of time on it, but did not found any working solution ...
I have tried the following code .. but always else case is running "didnt find login form1"
I have tried another *coders11* inplemented api but it was also deprecated...
I found many other solutions but not in php ... I am looking for solution in php...

````
class googleAlerts{
    public function createAlert($alert){
        $USERNAME = 'XXXXXX@gmail.com';
        $PASSWORD = 'YYYYYY';
        $COOKIEFILE = 'cookies.txt';

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $COOKIEFILE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $COOKIEFILE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 120);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 120);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,
            'https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?hl=en&service=alerts&continue=http://www.google.com/alerts/manage');
        $data = curl_exec($ch);

        $formFields = $this->getFormFields($data);

        $formFields['Email']  = $USERNAME;
        $formFields['Passwd'] = $PASSWORD;
        unset($formFields['PersistentCookie']);

        $post_string = '';
        foreach($formFields as $key => $value) {
            $post_string .= $key . '=' . urlencode($value) . '&';
        }

        $post_string = substr($post_string, 0, -1);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLoginAuth');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_string);

        $result = curl_exec($ch);

        if (strpos($result, '<title>') === false) {
            return false;

        } else {
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.google.com/alerts');
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 0);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, null);

            $result = curl_exec($ch);

            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.google.com/alerts/create');
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 0);
            $result = curl_exec($ch);
            //var_dump($result);
            $result = $this->getFormFieldsCreate($result);
            $result['q'] = $alert;
            $result['t'] = '7';
            $result['f'] = '1';
            $result['l'] = '0';
            $result['e'] = 'feed';
            unset($result['PersistentCookie']);

            $post_string = '';
            foreach($result as $key => $value) {
                $post_string .= $key . '=' . urlencode($value) . '&';
            }

            $post_string = substr($post_string, 0, -1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_string);
            $result = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.google.com/alerts/manage');
            $result = curl_exec($ch);
            if (preg_match_all('%'.$alert.'(?=</a>).*?<a href=[\'"]http://www.google.com/alerts/feeds/([^\'"]+)%i', $result, $matches)) {
                return ('http://www.google.com/alerts/feeds/'.$matches[1][0]);
            } else {
                return false;
            }


        }
    }

    private function getFormFields($data)
    {
        if (preg_match('/(<form.*?id=.?gaia_loginform.*?<\/form>)/is', $data, $matches)) {
            $inputs = $this->getInputs($matches[1]);

            return $inputs;
        } else {
            die('didnt find login form');
        }
    }
    private function getFormFieldsCreate($data)
    {
        if (preg_match('/(<form.*?name=.?.*?<\/form>)/is', $data, $matches)) {
            $inputs = $this->getInputs($matches[1]);

            return $inputs;
        } else {
            die('didnt find login form1');
        }
    }


    private function getInputs($form)
    {
        $inputs = array();

        $elements = preg_match_all('/(<input[^>]+>)/is', $form, $matches);

        if ($elements > 0) {
            for($i = 0; $i < $elements; $i++) {
                $el = preg_replace('/\s{2,}/', ' ', $matches[1][$i]);

                if (preg_match('/name=(?:["\'])?([^"\'\s]*)/i', $el, $name)) {
                    $name  = $name[1];
                    $value = '';

                    if (preg_match('/value=(?:["\'])?([^"\'\s]*)/i', $el, $value)) {
                        $value = $value[1];
                    }

                    $inputs[$name] = $value;
                }
            }
        }

        return $inputs;
    }
}
$alert = new googleAlerts;
echo $alert->createAlert('YOUR ALERT');```
````

Answer (score 0):

You can't login into google alerts with password and email anymore, you would have to pre-create cookies by login into google alerts and copying them out of the dev console and then passing them as argument when doing a curl request. Check out my google alerts api i have written in php. Maybe that helps you out https://github.com/Trivo25/google-alerts-api-php